# map_values() for Ruby hashes?

Tags: ruby, hash

I miss a `Hash` method in Ruby to transform/map only the values of the hash.

```
h = { 1 => [9,2,3,4], 2 => [6], 3 => [5,7,1] }
h.map_values { |v| v.size }
#=> { 1 => 4, 2 => 1, 3 => 3 }
```

How do you archive this in Ruby?

**Update**: I'm looking for an implementation of `map_values()`.

```
# more examples
h.map_values { |v| v.reduce(0, :+) }
#=> { 1 => 18, 2 => 6, 3 => 13 } 

h.map_values(&:min)
#=> { 1 => 2, 2 => 6, 3 => 1 }
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: @shivam The last line/comment of the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can monkey-patch the hash class, like this

```
class Hash
  def map_values
    map { |k, v|
      [k, yield(v)]
    }.to_h
  end
end

p ({1 => [1,1,1,1], 2 => [2], 3 => [3,3,3]}.map_values { |e| e.size })
```

Comment: Nice answer, it seems generic with use of blocks

Comment: Thanks, it shows one possible implementation of `map_values()`.

Answer (score 16):

Ruby 2.4 introduced the methods [`Hash#transform_values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) and [`Hash#transform_values!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values-21) with the desired behavoir.

```
h = { 1=>[9, 2, 3, 4], 2=>[6], 3=>[5, 7, 1] }
h.transform_values { |e| e.size }
#=> {1=>4, 2=>1, 3=>3}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`Hash#update`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html) for this:

```
h = { 1 => [9, 2, 3, 4], 2 => [6], 3 => [5, 7, 1] }

h.update(h) { |_, v| v.size }
#=> { 1 => 4, 2 => 1, 3 => 3 }
```

It replaces all values that have duplicate keys in one hash with that of another, or, if a block is given, with the result of calling the block. You can pass the original hash as the argument to ensure all values are replaced.

---

Note that this modifies the hash in place! If you want to preserve the original hash, `dup` it first:

```
h.dup.update(h) { |_, v| v.size }
#=> { 1 => 4, 2 => 1, 3 => 3 }

h
#=> { 1 => [9, 2, 3, 4], 2 => [6], 3 => [5, 7, 1] }
```

Comment: Good one, Drenmi! For the non-mutating case just use `merge`. Readers: to be more specific, this uses the form of `Hash#update` (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged, which here is all keys.

Comment: I hate your opening line. This is a perfectly good way of modifying a hash's values. Is it obsure? Is `a.reduce(:+)` obscure? Yes to both, the first time you see them. Also, that line is akin to: "You'll probably say 'no', but I was wondering if you'd go to a movie with me".

Comment: Good point there @CarySwoveland. Akin to starting a speech with "I am no speaker, but ..." :-)

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick for you

```
h = { 1 => [1,1,1,1], 2 => [2], 3 => [3,3,3] }
h.map {|k,v| [k, v.size] }.to_h
```

Answer (score 2):

No `map`, just `each`

```
h = { 1 => [1,1,1,1], 2 => [2], 3 => [3,3,3] }
h.each{|k,v| h[k] = v.size}
```

Comment: If wrapped in a method you of course need to add a last line `h`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by:

```
h.map { |a, b| [a, b.size] }.to_h
#=> {1=>4, 2=>1, 3=>3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more way to achieve it:

```
h = { 1 => [1,1,1,1], 2 => [2], 3 => [3,3,3] }
p h.keys.zip(h.values.map(&:size)).to_h
#=> {1=>4, 2=>1, 3=>3}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an implementation of this method in the DeepEnumerable library: https://github.com/dgopstein/deep_enumerable/

It's called `shallow_map_values`:

```
>> require 'deep_enumerable'    
>> h = { 1 => [9,2,3,4], 2 => [6], 3 => [5,7,1] }    
>> h.shallow_map_values { |v| v.size }
=> {1=>4, 2=>1, 3=>3}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hash.each_value.map { |value| puts(value) }` to iterate over all values of a hash.